# Galois subextensions in a Galois extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F \subset E \subset L$ be fields such that $L/E$ and $E/F$ are both Galois extensions. Is $L/F$ necessarily a Galois extension?

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: Actually, I have no good clue for an answer... This question is an exercise in Patrick Morandi's Galois theory textbook, and it's stated also as a question. By trying to prove the answer is yes, I got to a point where I would need to prove that automorphisms in Gal(E|F) extend to automorphisms in Gal(L|F), but I don't know whether this should be true.

Comment: Marco, that exactly is the problem - well done identifying it (+1). It may happen that an element $z$ of $E$ has a square root in $L$. But the $F$-conjugate of $z$, say $\sigma(z)$ fails to have a square root in $L$. Which makes it impossible to extend $\sigma$ to an automorphism of $L$, and takes us to Praphulla's (+1) hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints :

- Any (well behaving) degree $2$ extension is Normal.
- Not all degree $4$ extensions are Normal.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

$F = \mathbb{Q}$,  $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ and $L = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$ constitute a counterexample. Thanks a lot Praphulla and Jyrki for the hints.